# How to access a value - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Just a quick Python question:
How do I access the value assigned to the 'name' variable below?

```
('status', {'id': 8, 'name': 'In Progress'})
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: @skaul05: That should have been an answer, with some explanation added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ('status', {'id': 8, 'name': 'In Progress'})
print(a[1]['name'])
```

Comment: "tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str"

Know why?

Comment: for i in changes[1]:
        if 'category' in i:
            category[1] = i[1]['name']
        elif 'status' in i:
            status[1] = i[1]['name']

**thats the code I use**